# Finding coordinates on a grid (2D array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm currently trying to solve a problem I failed to solve in a white-board mock interview. I got stuck a few times. Any help is appreciated.

The question was worded as such:

> Given an NxN grid with an array of lamp coordinates. Each lamp provides illumination to every square on their x-axis, every square on their y-axis, and every square that lies in their diagonal (think of the Queen in chess). Given an array of query coordinates, determine whether that point is illuminated or not.
>
> The catch is when checking a query, all lamps adjacent to or on that query gets turned off. If you visit a coordinate/cell, turn off all lamps that are in that coordinates or adjacent. Two cells are adjacent if they share the same edge or corner.
>
> - write a function `checkLampIllumination(N, lamps, queries)`
> - `N` : size of the grid
> - `lamps` : coordinates of a lamp
> - `queries` : coordinates on the grid to be checked if they are lit or not

The test case I was given was:

```
N = 8

lamps = [
    [1,6],
    [5,6],
    [7,3],
    [3,2]
]

queries = [
    [4,4],
    [6,6],
    [8,1],
    [3,2],
    [2,3]
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['DARK','LIGHT','DARK','DARK','LIGHT']
```

Second Test case:

```
checkLampIllumination(8, [[4,3],[4,4]], [[3,4],[7,6]])

N = 8

lamps = [
    [4,3],
    [4,4]
]

queries = [
    [3,4],
    [7,6]
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
['DARK','LIGHT']
```

Here is my current stab at it. I think the current solution just creates the grid. I really don't know where to go from here.

```
const checkLampIllumination=(N, lamps, queries) => {
    var gridNxN = []
    var row = []
    for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i.toString().indexOf('0') !== -1) {
            row.push(i)
            gridNxN.push(row)
            row = []
        } else {
            row.push(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for visualization of the lamps and queries, you can play with a [pixel art generator](https://jsfiddle.net/Riham/rBmJ7/) if you want.

I'd first create a helper function `isAdjacent` to check whether two points are adjacent. Then, iterate over each query (target square), and check if any lamp illuminates the target. The problem reduces to checking that:

- The lamp is not adjacent, and at least one of the following is true:
- The lamp either has the same X coordinate, or
- the same Y coordinate, or
- they're on the same diagonal, which can be checked by seeing if the difference between the lamp's and target's X coordinates is equal to the difference between the lamp's and target's Y coordinates.

Putting this into code, you get:

```js
let lamp = [
  [1, 6],
  [5, 6],
  [7, 3],
  [3, 2]
];
const queries = [
  [4, 4],
  [6, 6],
  [8, 1],
  [3, 2],
  [2, 3]
]

const isAdjacent = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => Math.abs(x2 - x1) < 2 && Math.abs(y2 - y1) < 2;
queries.forEach(([checkX, checkY]) => {
  const thisSquareIlluminated = lamp.some(([lampX, lampY]) => (
    !isAdjacent(checkX, checkY, lampX, lampY) && (
      lampX === checkX
      || lampY === checkY
      || Math.abs(lampX - checkX) === Math.abs(lampY - checkY)
    )
  ));
  console.log(thisSquareIlluminated ? 'LIGHT' : 'DARK');
});
```

I wouldn't recommend building the illuminated squares beforehand, because then, given a query, you wouldn't know if a particular square with illumination only has illumination due to an adjacent lamp or not, at least not without iterating through all the lamps again - better to just iterate through them once, after a query is selected.

Note that the `N = 8` input is not used anywhere - it's a red herring, unless you also need to check for whether lamps/queries are in valid spaces on the board as well.

Comment: The original wording was not really clear for me, but your isAdjacent helper doesn't consider cells at diagonals to be adjacent (e.g `isAdjacent(1,1,2,2)` returns false) I don't know if it is a problem though. Also, while I'm really not sure of how to read it, I think the catch part means that the grid is not stateless (i.e, once you switched off a lamp by checking on it, it should remain switched off => mutate the `lamp` array), so for instance if there were a last [1, 6] query, it should return Dark. But once again, I'm really not sure of my reading...

Comment: From your code and the fiddle, its starting to make more sense, especially visualizing the diagonal. I think N comes into play to make a grid. For example, NxN would make a grid with 8 rows and 9 columns. they might have given N becaue the could be smaller or bigger. but im not too sure

Comment: @TrueLife but they didn't say what should happen in case of out-of-the grid inputs. So the grid size makes very little sense.

Comment: @Kaiido That is true, I didn't think of that edge case

Comment: @TrueLife I changed the `isAdjacent` function in light of diagonals counting as adjacent, and now `filter` the `lamp` on each iteration.

Comment: @CertainPerformance there is a bug, I used the test case I posted and the second test case `checkLampIllumination(0,[[4,3],[4,4]],[[3,4],[7,6]])` both didn't return the correct results. For the second test it should be `['DARK','LIGHT']`

Comment: also can you shred light on why you used `.some`

Comment: @TrueLife Why would the second query have `LIGHT`? The first query on `3, 4` is adjacent to both lamps (which are `[[4,3],[4,4]]`), so after the first query, the lamp array has been emptied - the only two lamps have been turned off.

Comment: @TrueLife `.some` checks for whether any items in an array pass a given test - it's *the* array method to use in that sort of situation. (only need to identify whether at least one lamp illuminates the target square, after all)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I believe its cause of this part of the question `catch is when checking a query all lamps adjacent to, or on, that query gets turned off.`

Comment: @TrueLife Well, given the problem statement, the code performs as intended - I get `['DARK','DARK']`, which makes sense, because there are no lamps to illuminate anything once the first query turns them off.

Comment: @CertainPerformance True, but I think the grids should be reset each time a new coordinate is checked. I tried to alter the code to do that but I can't come up with a solution as of yet.

Comment: @TrueLife That seems to contradict your original clarification. Ok, I'll roll back the code to the original version which didn't mutate the `lamps` array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think because your code is only testing the adjacent coordinates so its missing coordinates that are diagonal

Answer (score 1):

Since we're not in an interview at the moment, I've decided to keep the code not compact, so it can be understood easier. You can shorten it if you want. I love this kind of problems, so I took my time with it.

Also I've updated the visual grid. Now you can see the states of the grid as it changes.

```js
var lamps = [
    [1,6],
    [5,6],
    [7,3],
    [3,2]
];

var queries = [
    [4,4],
    [6,6],
    [8,1],
    [3,2],
    [2,3]
];

/* ==================== VISUAL GRID ==================== */

function arrayFlatten(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item instanceof Array) {
            result = result.concat(arrayFlatten(item));
        } else {
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
}

function createGrid(lamps, queries) {
    var grid = document.createElement("table");
    grid.classList.add("grid");
    var gridSize = Math.max.apply(null, arrayFlatten([lamps, queries])) + 1;
    
    document.body.appendChild(grid);
    
    // create cells
    for (var i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement("td");
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        grid.appendChild(row);
    }
    
    // add lamps
    lamps.forEach(lamp => grid.rows[lamp[1]].cells[lamp[0]].classList.add("lamp"));

    var illuminatedRows = Array.from(new Set(lamps.map(([lampX, lampY]) => lampY)));
    var illuminatedCols = Array.from(new Set(lamps.map(([lampX, lampY]) => lampX)));
    illuminatedRows.sort();
    illuminatedCols.sort();

    // add lights
    // horizontal
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
        if (illuminatedRows.includes(i)) {
            Array.from(grid.rows[i].cells).forEach(cell => cell.classList.add("horizontal-light"));
        }
    }
    // vertical
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < grid.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            if (illuminatedCols.includes(j)) {
                grid.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add("vertical-light");
            }
        }
    }
    // diagonal
    for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < grid.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
            var x = j;
            var y = i;
            lamps.forEach(function (lamp) {
                if (isDiagonal(lamp[0], lamp[1], x, y)) {
                    grid.rows[i].cells[j].classList.add("diagonal-light");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    
}

createGrid(lamps, queries);

/* ==================== CALCULATION ==================== */

function isHorizontal(y1, y2) {
    return y1 == y2;
}

function isVertical(x1, x2) {
    return x1 == x2;
}

function isDiagonal(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.abs(x1 - x2) == Math.abs(y1 - y2);
}

function isIlluminated(queryX, queryY, lampX, lampY) {
    return isHorizontal(queryY, lampY) || isVertical(queryX, lampX) || isDiagonal(queryX, queryY, lampX, lampY);
}

function isAdjacent(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    return Math.abs(x2 - x1) < 2 && Math.abs(y2 - y1) < 2
}

// check every lamp for each query
function checkLamps(lamps, queryX, queryY) {
    // store checks for each lamp for a query
    var checks = [];
    // loop every lamp
    for (var i = lamps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var lampX = lamps[i][0];
        var lampY = lamps[i][1];
        // check if the target cell is adjacent to the current lamp
        if (isAdjacent(queryX, queryY, lampX, lampY)) {
            console.log("Query (" + [queryX, queryY].join() + ") is adjacent to lamp (" + [lampX, lampY].join() + "). Removing this lamp.");
            // lamp is adjacent; remove it
            lamps.splice(i, 1);
            // create a grid with the new state (for visual purposes)
            createGrid(lamps, queries);
            // skip this lamp
            continue;
        } else {
            // storing the check for the current lamp
            checks.push(isIlluminated(queryX, queryY, lampX, lampY));
        }
    }
    // if all checks are false, it's dark
    // if there's even a single true, that means the cell is illuminated by a lamp
    if (checks.includes(true)) {
        console.log("(" + [queryX, queryY].join() + ") is LIGHT");
    } else {
        console.log("(" + [queryX, queryY].join() + ") is DARK");
    }
}

function checkLampIllumination(lamps, queries) {
    // create a local copy of lamps because it'll (might) mutate
    var lamps = lamps.slice();
    // loop queries
    queries.forEach(([queryX, queryY]) => checkLamps(lamps, queryX, queryY));
}

checkLampIllumination(lamps, queries);
```

```css
.grid {
    background-color: black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: left;
}
.grid td {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 50%);
}
.grid td.horizontal-light,
.grid td.vertical-light,
.grid td.diagonal-light {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, .33);
}
.grid td.horizontal-light.vertical-light,
.grid td.horizontal-light.diagonal-light,
.grid td.vertical-light.diagonal-light {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, .45);
}
.grid td.horizontal-light.vertical-light.diagonal-light {
    background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 80%, .6);
}
.grid td.lamp {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%) !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where are you trying to determine whether that point is illuminated or not?

Comment: @TrueLife Sorry. I've had a busy day yesterday. Didn't have time to actually look into the problem, but just created a visual grid. I've updated my answer now.